# How do I run the same command via Node.js fabric-ca-client module?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to run enroll and register using Node.js's [fabric-ca-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-ca-client) module, but I'm confused with the [API docs](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/FabricCAServices.html#register). Can you guys help to convert the command to Node.js?

```sh
./bin/fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://admin:adminpw@example.com:7056 \
--caname ca --tls.certfiles tls-ca-cert.pem;

./bin/fabric-ca-client register --caname ca --tls.certfiles tls-ca-cert.pem \
--id.name ordereradmin --id.secret ordereradminpw \
--id.type user -u https://example.com:7056;
```

Answer (score 0):

For first part, an example might be:

```
// Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
    const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
      enrollmentID: "admin",
      enrollmentSecret: "adminpw"
    });

    const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(
      "Org1MSP",
      enrollment.certificate,
      enrollment.key.toBytes()
    );

    wallet.import("Admin@org1.example.com", identity);
    console.log(
      'Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet'
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to enroll admin user "admin": ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
```

For second part - there is an example of `register` and `enrol` using fabric-ca-client in Fabcar here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/registerUser.js#L44. Obviously for an orderer it would require the right type eg `orderer`,the correct affiliation etc etc.  This Fabric 1.4 example 'requires' `fabric-network` which includes the packages `fabric-ca-client` and `fabric-client` FYI.

Comment: ok.. it seems like it's not a few liner and I would also need [fabric-network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-network).. I thought it'll be as simple as the CLI.. will try this out and let you know.. thanks!